# Instr from ubound array range

Tags: arrays, vba, search, excel

For search in one column (column B) i use this code

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

txt = TextBox1.Text
lt = Len(TextBox1.Text)
If lt = 0 Then Exit Sub

x = Range("b1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    If InStr(x(i, 2), txt) Then
            s = s & "~" & x(i, 1) & "         >>>>" & x(i, 2)

    Else
    End If
Next i

ListBox1.List = Split(Mid(s, 2), "~")
End Sub
```

But how to change this code to look for txt in some column (Column B and Column A) or (Column B and Column A and Column C) at once?

so if i have

```
in column A 
first
second
thirdFirst

in column B
notfirst
secondFirst
third
```

with this code i look only in column B and get

```
if txt= first
result
first notfirst
second secondFirst
```

but i cant find thirdFist values from column A
 so i need get result like

```
if txt= first
result
first notfirst
second secondFirst
thirdFirst third
```

Comment: Code looks for txt in column 'B' but returns value from 'A' as well. So how the code should behave if it looks in 'A'? In that case array 'x' will have one column only.

Comment: but searching only in b column i need search in two columns a and b

Comment: What I am talking about is that if you use it like this: x = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value then it will not work. So to search in column 'A' does not make sense. It is possible to use the code as it is starting with column 'B'.

Comment: I know it!!! and want to know how to do that what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I hope I understood your question right. Here example of code and the result for sample data on the picture. HTH.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim txt, values, valuesFiltered, r, c, rowsCount, columnsCount, check

    txt = "first"
    If Len(txt) = 0 Then _
        Exit Sub

    ' get all values from last used cell in column 'A' to upperRightCell
    ' e.g. "B1', 'C1' etc.
    Dim lastUsedCellInColumn_A As Range
    Set lastUsedCellInColumn_A = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

    Dim upperRightCell As Range
    Set upperRightCell = Range("C1")

    values = Range(lastUsedCellInColumn_A, upperRightCell).Value
    rowsCount = UBound(values, 1)
    columnsCount = UBound(values, 2)

    If columnsCount <= 1 Then _
        Err.Raise 12345, , "At least two columns must be used."

    For r = 1 To rowsCount
        For c = 1 To columnsCount

            If InStr(values(r, c), txt) = 0 Then _
                GoTo next_column

            If c > 1 Then
                ' columns B, C, D and so on: take value from neighbour cell on the left
                check = values(r, c) & ">>>>" & values(r, c - 1)
            Else
                ' column A: take value from neighbour cell on the right
                check = values(r, c + 1) & ">>>>" & values(r, c)
            End If

            ' do not add duplicate values
            If IsArray(valuesFiltered) = False Then
                ReDim valuesFiltered(0)
                valuesFiltered(0) = check
            Else
                If UBound(Filter(valuesFiltered, check)) = -1 Then
                    ReDim Preserve valuesFiltered(UBound(valuesFiltered) + 1)
                    valuesFiltered(UBound(valuesFiltered)) = check
                End If
            End If

next_column:
        Next c
    Next r

    If Not IsEmpty(valuesFiltered) Then _
        ListBox1.List = valuesFiltered
End Sub
```

[image]